# Make image links open in a new tab?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, hyperlink, image

I have an image web part with a preview of another page on my Sharepoint online site, I have added a hyperlink to this image, however I would like to modify this to open the second page in a new tab instead of the current one. For normal text-based links I can easily change this option, but there doesn't seem to be one for image-based links? Does Sharepoint online support this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my knowledge, we do not have this feature to open the image-based links in a new tab. You will need to right click and choose open link in a new tab. Or you can middle click the image.

Here is a [userVoice post](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/38425315-allow-open-link-in-new-tab-on-image-web-part-hyper) you can vote.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll go and vote on the link you posted. I thought a simple feature like this would be available in Sharepoint